# Brand new React Native CLI (2.0.1) project fails on build (iOS)

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, react-native-cli

I'm trying to build a literal brand-new just-initialized project with React Native CLI (latest version) and I get the below avalanche of error messages and the build fails.  It's such a massive clump of error messages that my Terminal can't even show the whole thing.  Just initialized with `npx react-native init`, didn't touch it otherwise.  Older projects that I built previously build just fine but any new projects I try to build give the same result.  I've tried to initialize four new projects and gotten the same result.  MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, XCode 11.7, React 16.13.1, React Native 0.63.4, React Native CLI 2.0.1.

Not sure how to produce a minimum reproducible result as this literally is happening with a brand new project.

Have tried restarting my machine, creating five separate brand new RN CLI projects, looking in the XCode derived data folder, seeing if there are any logs.

This started after I tried to fix another error by deleting project files in the DerivedData folder, that's the only thing I can think of that might have caused this.

Here's the first part of the error messages, I can't post the whole thing because of the character limit.  The rest of it is in this Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kQ7Wg8EK26ivOqEdz4XIM2dm5Xe33zCvU6kQ7vWyHRw/edit?usp=sharing

```
noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Flipper-DoubleConversion-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion/include -I/Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Flipper-DoubleConversion -I/Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-DoubleConversion -I/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion -Wno-unreachable-code -include /Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Flipper-DoubleConversion/Flipper-DoubleConversion-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bignum.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bignum.dia -c /Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion/bignum.cc -o /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bignum.o

CompileC /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bignum-dtoa.o /Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion/bignum-dtoa.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/owenwexler/code/tuts/WillItBuild/ios/Pods
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.7.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Flipper-DoubleConversion-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Flipper-DoubleConversion-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Flipper-DoubleConversion-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/owenwexler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WillItBuild-blcmrlwkxskfhxcgewqpvkcvjpxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Flipper-DoubleConversion-project-headers.hmap
```

Comment: Just tried with Android and it works - only fails like that with iOS.

Comment: Tried deleting entirely and reinstalling XCode and Cocoapods... that didn't fix it.